# Use jQuery to animate the re-position of DIV's after fadeOut (fiddle)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

To get a better idea of what I'm trying to do, I have this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/tfisher9180/7efagjhj/1/

When you click the button 3 squares fade out, and then afterwards the orange square immediately snaps up because of the absence of the others.

I want to know if there's a way to animate that to look more fluid so that the orange box slides up as well.

```
.square {transition: all 0.3s linear;}
```

This did not work as I expected.

**UPDATE:**

*Marking @anied as correct answer for working with me a bit and helping to fix positioning. Everyone's solutions were awesome though and worked nicely. +1 for all and will have to try out a few to see which looks best!!!*

Comment: Should `.square-orange` fade out?

Comment: No I just want it to slide into its new position after the divs are removed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the problem with using a CSS transition here is that there is no CSS property of the orange box that is changing when the boxes around it disappear-- it is simply reflowing to the new position in the DOM based on the change the display property of these other boxes.  I think if you want this to work you will have to write a custom bit of jQuery code that fades the boxes out but doesn't immediately hide them, but instead slides them up and out of sight.

Try something like this:

```
$('#sort').on('click', function() {
  $('.square').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass('square-orange')) {
      $(this).animate({'opacity' : 0}, 400, 'swing', function () {
          $(this).slideUp();
      });
    }
  });
});
```

edit:
Regarding the skip-- not really sure exactly, but I tried replacing the `slideUp` with a custom replacement and it seemed to resolve it:

```
$('#sort').on('click', function() {
  $('.square').each(function() {
        if (!$(this).hasClass('square-orange')) {
        $(this).animate({'opacity': 0}, 400, 'swing', function() {
            $(this).animate({'height': 0}, 400, 'swing');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

edit (again): actually, looking now I see that one problem is that the top `.row` still is retaining height after the boxes within slide-up.... you might need to slide that up as well, depending on your requirements..

edit:

OK, last time, fixed your positioning a bit-- I think this works:

```js
$('#sort').on('click', function() {
  $('.square').each(function() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass('square-orange')) {
     $(this).animate({'opacity': 0}, 400, 'swing', function() {
       $(this).animate({'height' : 0}, 400, 'swing');
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.row {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
.square {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.square-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.square-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.square-orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.square-purple {
  background-color: purple;
}

#sort {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #414141;
  border: 0;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row row-top clearfix">
    <div class="square square-red"></div>
    <div class="square square-blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row row-bottom clearfix">
    <div class="square square-orange"></div>
    <div class="square square-purple"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="sort">Sort Orange</button>
```

Comment: This worked really well, however there's a slight skip towards the top I think in this updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tfisher9180/7efagjhj/4/ do you know why that might be?

Comment: It looks like doing your original solution with @developernator solution worked. Adding '100' to slideUp()

Comment: Sort of-- I think his solution is masking the problem because his slide-up happens quickly enough that you can't see the jump.  The problem is because your boxes are positioned with inline-block, even when they have height of 0 the containing row still has height.  Because `slideUp` then adds `display:none` at the end the row then abruptly loses its height.  I'm futzing around with fixing the positioning to make it work more naturally.

Comment: @TimothyFisher I adjusted your positioning so that it can naturally slide up at any speed without issue now.

Answer (score 2):

Use this jquery:

`$('#sort').on('click', function() {
   $("row").eq(0).css("min-height",$(".square-red").height()+"px");
   $(".square:not(.square-orange)").fadeOut().slideUp();
   $(".square-red").parent().slideUp();`});

Comment: This gives a cool effect too. Everything sort of happens at once which is a nice alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
$('#sort').on('click', function() {
  $('.square').each(function() {
     if (!$(this).hasClass('square-orange')) {
       $(this).animate({
         opacity: 0
       }, 500, function() {
         $(this).slideUp(100);
       });
     } 
  });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7efagjhj/7/

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `position` of `.square-orange` and `#sort` to `absolute` and set `top` `.position().top` before `.fadeOut()` begins, use `.promise()`, `.animate()` to animate `.square-orange` when `.square:not(.square-orange)` elements animation completes

```js
$('#sort').on('click', function() {

  $(this).add(".square-orange")
    .each(function() {
      $(this).css({
        "position": "absolute",
        top: $(this).position().top
      })
    })

  $('.square:not(.square-orange)').each(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  })
  .promise()
    .then(function() {
      $(".square-orange")
        .animate({
          top: 20
        }, 1000, "linear")
    })

});
```

```css
.square {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.square-red {
  background-color: red;
}
.square-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
.square-orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
.square-purple {
  background-color: purple;
}
#sort {
  margin-top: 30px;
  background-color: #414141;
  border: 0;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square square-red"></div>
    <div class="square square-blue"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="square square-orange"></div>
    <div class="square square-purple"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="sort">Sort Orange</button>
```

jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/7efagjhj/8/